# Durandal 2.1: Child Router with child views results in jerky transitions

Tags: durandal

I'm following the example in the HTML Samples project for child routers / nested views.  Instead of having a sidebar to navigate, I'm using tabs.

When I click from one tab to the next, the router updates along with the view/viewmodel - composition completes without a hitch.

The transition from the current view to the new view is jumpy though - the view fades in at the top of the page, and then jumps down to where it should be once the transition completes.

Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem, mainly in older versions of IE. We had upgraded to durandal 2.1 and noticed that child router transitions that worked perfectly under durandal 2.01 were not working properly. The content faded in at the top before being repositioned to the correct location when the transition completed. We compared the 2.1 and 2.01 versions of the entrance transition and noticed some changes in the CSS it used as well as some code to detect IE. As we were under severe time constraints we rolled back the transition to the 2.01 version.  This worked perfectly. Hope it helps.